# docker-compose build leads to client and server don't have same version (client : 1.18, server: 1.17)

Tags: ubuntu, docker, docker-compose

I tried to build docker using `docker-compose build` but facing issue like `client and server don't have same version (client : 1.18, server: 1.17)`.

I found solution using

```
curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.2.0/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > /usr/local/bin/docker-compose``

chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose`.
```

When tried again build I got `Unsupported config option for services service: 'nginx'`

docker-compose.yml use `version: '2'`

Current version of docker

```
Client version: 1.6.2
Client API version: 1.18
Go version (client): go1.2.1
Git commit (client): 7c8fca2
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.6.2
Server API version: 1.18
```

frankly speaking I'm totally new for this, And even not understand what to do.

Please assist me.

Comment: Instead of building, just download the correct *matching* binaries. You'll find installation instructions on Docker's site anyway

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos How can i select perfect matching binaries? Because I'm new in Ubuntu and using Mint.

Comment: You should really [read the documents](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/).  You can just `sudo apt-get install docker-engine` once you configure the proper package source. As for downloading binaries directly, just make sure you download files with the same version number

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm read this installation guide but confused on step #7 which entry I use. Just for info ''3.16.0-38-generic'

Comment: What *is* your Ubuntu version?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Linux Mint 17.2 64-bit

Comment: The versions of Docker client, Docker engine, and docker-compose are over a year old. I'd recommend upgrading. This is a fast moving project, and quite a lot has changed since then.

Comment: @BMitch after upgrading got ' client and server don't have same version (client : 1.22, server: 1.18)' error

Comment: API 1.18 is still Docker's year old release (1.6.x). Don't upgrade using the Unbuntu repos, pull directly from Docker following their install instructions to add the Docker repo.